# How to display a cheat sheet list of currently assigned key bindings in ReSharper?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, keyboard-shortcuts, keymapping

I vaguely remember ReSharper had a feature that displays a cheat sheet of all current key bindings / key mappings / hotkeys / assigned shorcuts. It was very convenient to have at a glance look at them, instead of the normal built-in `Environments/Options/Keyboard` screen. I do not seem to be able to figure out how to bring this cheat sheet up. Any pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tick the following checkbox `ReSharper | Options | Environment | Keyboard & Menus | Enable Shortcut Browser`. When press left Ctrl key three times in a row.